# How to start SimpleHTTPServer in background with commands.getoutput

Tags: python, python-2.7, simplehttpserver

I am trying to start `SimpleHTTPServer` in background with `commands.getoutput`, but unable to do so.

```
commands.getoutput("python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080 &> /dev/null &")

(Pdb++) n
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
sh: -c: line 0: `{ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080 &> /dev/null &; } 2>&1'
```

When I am executing the same thing on linux prompt, it is working fine:

```
bash-4.2$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080 &> /dev/null &
[2] 28460

bash-4.2$ ps -ef | grep SimpleHTTPServer
x  27624 22693  0 16:54 pts/16   00:00:00 python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

Can someone help me figuring out if I am missing anything here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you've tagged Python 2.7, why are you still using the `commands` interface? It's been deprecated since Python 2.6 and the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module should be used instead:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["python", "-m", "SimpleHTTPServer", "8080"])
```

should do it. Or, even better, run it with `nohup` as your script exit might kill it:

```
subprocess.Popen(["nohup", "python", "-m", "SimpleHTTPServer", "8080"])
```

To ignore the output you can pass `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL` to the `subprocess.Popen()` call if you're using Python 3.3+, or you can open `/dev/null` yourself:

```
import os
import subprocess

with open(os.devnull, 'w') as t:
    subprocess.Popen(["nohup","python","-m","SimpleHTTPServer","8080"], stdout=t, stderr=t)
```

Comment: I want to start SimpleHTTPServer in background.

Comment: @npatel - the above **will** run it in the background.

Comment: I am getting this exception: `TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings`, looks like `8080` is to be changed to `"8080"`.

Comment: @npatel - I've forgot to quote the port number in the initial answer, it seems you've been quicker to pick up the initial code before I had the chance to update it. Check the latest answer version.

Comment: Thanks @ zwer. Will use subprocess instead of commands. Thanks for pointing that out.